# What was the coded message that Happy Hogan sent to Nick Fury?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, spider-man-far-from-home

During the final fight, Happy Hogan calls Nick Fury to warn him about Mysterio's real plan. Happy says a something about going through Tony's old stuff. And Nick Fury replies with "Never call this number again".

Later when they meet up, Happy says "Did you get my coded message?" and that it translates to 'Looks can be deceiving'.

What was the coded message and how does it decode? Was it like a pre-setup distress code or was it a simple 'first letter of a word acronym' kinda code?

Comment: Given that Happy's password is “password”, we can probably assume that he's not conversant in the finer details of cryptography.

Comment: The joke is that it wasn't much of a code. Happy just makes up a story about finding Fury's surfboard among Tony's belongings, but Fury doesn't seem like much of a surfer, so apparently _appearances can be deceiving_ (Happy literally says "appearances can be deceiving", he just wraps it in a ludicrous story).

Comment: @Oliver_C Do you remember the dialog word for word?

Comment: @Simba3696 - No, unfortunately I don't have perfect memory. But if Happy had actually been able to come up with a code, then he could have been more direct with his message, e.g. _"Don't trust Beck"_ or _"Beck is phony"_.

Comment: @Oliver_C, I got the dialogue. It went something like this.

Happy Hogan: Happy here, Happy Hogan.

Nick Fury: I know who you are

HH: Over at Mr. Stark's, going through his belongings, apparently there was this surfboard that you left behind. People over there said 'They didn't think that Nick Fury was a surfer'. And I said 'Appearances can be deceiving'.

NF: Not mine, don't ever call this number again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### It's not exactly a code...more of a hint.

It just meant that "not everything is as it appears"....

The implication is that Fury should be alerted to the fact that what is happening may be a deception (which Fury seems to be somewhat aware of anyway) but that by going back an investigating Tony's history more information might be obtained.

As we know, Beck and his cohorts all have previous history with Tony and/or Stark Enterprises which would be uncovered by some background checks.

Comment: I think that OP want to know the sentence which was coded by Happy and the way to decode it by Fury. But maybe it's because that's what I'm looking for in this question ^.^

Comment: There was no "sentence" to decode....he's just speaking cryptically not using an *actual* code. In other words he's telling Fury something without saying it directly.

Comment: I probably missed that part, as english is not my native, without english subtiltes, some element can slip away. Thanks :)

Comment: @Paulie_D is it not better to include some of those dialogues

Comment: Also, it might be a foreshadowing the true identity of "Nick Fury" in the post credit scene. You know, "appearance can be deceiving".

Answer (score 1):

According to [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/SpiderManFarFromHome) the coded message was something about the surfboard that everyone thought belonged to Fury. This has two references: one meta, one in universe.

Happy Hogan makes a sort-of-coded call to Nick Fury, **making up a story about a surfboard that everyone thought belonged to Fury**. Clearly they watched [Snakes on a Plane](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/SnakesOnAPlane) to the very end.

It's actually a coded message to [Talos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talos_the_Untamed), who is currently portraying Fury. **Talos's first appearance on Earth was as a surfer**, so this was confirmation that Mysterio was not on the up and up."

Answer (score 0):

It could be 1 of 2 things or both. Originally I was 100% sure it was about Mysterio and telling him to be careful, but it's not basically what it seems.

But after the ending credits, who knows. Seeing that, it's impossible to know who's who. The only convincing factor to prove Happy was legit was because he said something only Peter and him would know when Peter asked him.

Happy could have been letting him know he's aware it's not really him.